# Some questions about integration in a complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

On a two-dimension infinite plane we can always denote a complex number z which satisfies:
$$
z=x+iy\\
\bar{z}=x-iy
$$
and write down the surface element $dxdy$ as $\frac{1}{2}dzd\bar{z}$..Then my first question is when I meet a integral such as:
$$
I=\int f(z,\bar{z})dzd\bar{z}
$$
I have no idea how to evaluate it directly. All I can do is to transform it back to the variables (x,y) and do it in an ordinary method. I wonder what is the geometric meaning of $dzd\bar{z}$ and can I do the integral in a direct way?

Also, If we make a variables transformation:
$$
z \rightarrow \omega(z,\bar{z})
\\
\bar{z} \rightarrow \bar{\omega}(z,\bar{z})
$$
Is it still correct that
$$
I=\int f(z(w,\bar{w}),\bar{z}(w,\bar{w}))\frac{(\partial z,\partial \bar{z})}{(\partial \omega, \partial \bar{\omega})}d\omega d\bar{\omega}
$$
Where the Jacobi factor is same to one in a real variable transformation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $dzd\bar z = dx^2 + dy^2$, not $2dxdy$. In general, when dealing expressions like these, you treat $z$ and $\bar z$ as if they were independent variables. But you do have to be careful of the interpretation. There are applications where this works, but other applications where it does not.